# Visual Studio Code - Extensions Fail to Install, Says "Installing" then gets stuck

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just downloaded Nov version 1.8.1, Windows 10 VS Code.
Opens up fine.  I try installing any Extension, it just hangs, says Installing.
Never installs any extensions.

I tried making the .vsix path readable, i tried version 1.7, I tried uninstalling, re-installing.
I tried adding the core, removing the core, the SDK, removing the SDK, I tried running as Admin.
Nothing worked.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Try setting `http.proxy`

Comment: I"m on my home computer, never had a problem before.  Where would this setting be?

Comment: File -> Preferences -> User Settings

Comment: I'm @ home, never a problem like this:

Comment: // The proxy setting to use. If not set will be taken from the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables
  "http.proxy": "",

  // Whether the proxy server certificate should be verified against the list of supplied CAs.
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": true,

  // The value to send as the 'Proxy-Authorization' header for every network request.
  "http.proxyAuthorization": null,

Comment: I think there is a mess with trying to install VS2015 earlier, I'm going to re-install my VS 2010 Premium then try again. thanks.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6888) I opened. Like @Saravana said, setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` was the solution for me. Installing a local `.vsix` package needs the variables to be set, an unhelpful CLI output `Installing extensions...` and nothing in the logfiles. A very bad situation for problem solving.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me 
In the .vscode\extensions directory i found a file called obsolete and deleted it and was able to install extensions manually downloaded via VSIX

Comment: Just to add to @Ajay's answer, if you can't find the `obsolete` file, just close VS Code, delete the folder of the extension you were trying to install, and try to install it again.

Comment: My visual studio code is on Mac OS. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

With Linux it worked for me to delete the depending subfolder in

```
~/.vscode/extensions
```

thanks to [Aaron Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718559/aaron-lee)